# Identity with 2 Functions and Restrictions Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this homework question that I don't understand. I'm not sure where to start or what the purpose of this question is as to what it's suppose to do. If anyone could help that'd be great as I am new to Haskell. Below is the question:

```
identity x = x.  Your definition must have the form identity = e
where e mentions *only* ap and proj and parentheses.
ap f g x = f x (g x)
proj x y = x
identity :: a -> a
identity =
```

What is this above `identity` function suppose to accomplish or do after it's given an input?

thanks!

Comment: Nope. We're not going to do your homework assignment for you (in general, we aren't going to write code for you, no matter what the goal is). Tell us about the thoughts you've had, the code you've tried, and what went wrong; we will give you some hints about how to fix specific mistakes only.

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for a full solution as I stated "anyone could help" so a basic lead in the right direction as to where to start or maybe what the purpose of the above problem is.

Comment: You've told us what the homework question is. What question do *you* have? It might be, "What is the purpose of this homework question?"; but that is not really a technical question, and best served in a more discussion-like atmosphere (perhaps a forum or chat room). Or your question might be, "What is the meaning of this homework question?"; that is a more technical question, but should be made more specific. Are there specific words or phrases you don't understand? Is the syntax used unclear? Or your question might be something completely different. You need to clarify how we can help you.

Comment: My actual question is just what is this above function suppose to accomplish or do after it's given an input? I'm sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: @user3373360: they want you to write an `identity` function in [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) using only `ap` and `proj`. E.g. it may look like (not an actual answer) `identity = ap (proj ap)`, and if you call it like `identity 1234` it'll return `1234`.

Comment: The `ap` and `proj` functions are better known by other names. Can you do a bit of research and figure out what they are?

Comment: @dfeuer, `ap` is more haskellish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity function returns its input unchanged, as given by the homework question's specification that `identity x = x`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is `identity = (ap proj proj)`. That makes `identity x = proj x (proj x)` here `(proj x)` is a function but that does not matter as it is thrown away, giving you the equality `identity x = proj x _ = x`.